# Using rdrobust to calculate 2sls and getting error message stating "should be set within the range of x"

Tags: statistics, stata

I am trying to calculate a two stage least squares in Stata. My dataset looks like the following:

```
income bmi  health_index asian black q_o_l age  aide
100    19   99           1     0     87    23   1
0      21   87           1     0     76    29   0
1002   23   56           0     1     12    47   1
2200   24   67           1     0     73    43   0
2076   21   78           1     0     12    73   1
```

I am trying to use `rdrobust` to estimate the treatment effect. I used the following code:

```
rdrobust q_o_l aide health_index bmi income asian black age, c(10)
```

I varied the `income` variable with multiple polynomial forms and used multiple bandwidths. I keep getting the same error message stating:

```
c() should be set within the range of aide
```

I am assuming that this has to do with the bandwidth. How can I correct it?

Comment: The error message seems to be about your variable -aide-.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with the syntax. You wrote:

```
rdrobust q_o_l aide health_index bmi income asian black age, c(10)
```

This will ignore health_index-age variables, since you can only have one running variable. It will then try to use a cutoff of 10 for aide (the second variable is always the running one). Since aide is binary, Stata complains.

It's not obvious to me what makes sense in your setting, but here's an example demonstrating the problem and the two remedies:

```
. use "http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/r/rdrobust_senate.dta", clear

. rdrobust vote margin, c(0) covs(state year class termshouse termssenate population)

Covariate-adjusted sharp RD estimates using local polynomial regression.

      Cutoff c = 0 | Left of c  Right of c            Number of obs =       1108
-------------------+----------------------            BW type       =      mserd
     Number of obs |       491         617            Kernel        = Triangular
Eff. Number of obs |       309         279            VCE method    =         NN
    Order est. (p) |         1           1
    Order bias (q) |         2           2
       BW est. (h) |    17.669      17.669
       BW bias (b) |    28.587      28.587
         rho (h/b) |     0.618       0.618

Outcome: vote. Running variable: margin.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Method |   Coef.    Std. Err.    z     P>|z|    [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
      Conventional |  6.8862     1.3971   4.9291   0.000    4.14804      9.62438
            Robust |     -          -     4.2540   0.000    3.78697       10.258
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Covariate-adjusted estimates. Additional covariates included: 6

. sum margin

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      margin |      1,390    7.171159    34.32488       -100        100

. rdrobust vote margin state year class termshouse termssenate population, c(7)    // margin rang
> es from -100 to 100

Sharp RD estimates using local polynomial regression.

      Cutoff c = 7 | Left of c  Right of c            Number of obs =       1297
-------------------+----------------------            BW type       =      mserd
     Number of obs |       744         553            Kernel        = Triangular
Eff. Number of obs |       334         215            VCE method    =         NN
    Order est. (p) |         1           1
    Order bias (q) |         2           2
       BW est. (h) |    14.423      14.423
       BW bias (b) |    24.252      24.252
         rho (h/b) |     0.595       0.595

Outcome: vote. Running variable: margin.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Method |   Coef.    Std. Err.    z     P>|z|    [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
      Conventional |   .1531     1.7487   0.0875   0.930   -3.27434      3.58053
            Robust |     -          -     -0.0718  0.943   -4.25518      3.95464
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rdrobust vote margin state year class termshouse termssenate population, c(-100) // nonsensical
>  cutoff for margin
c() should be set within the range of margin
r(125);

end of do-file

r(125);
```

You might also find [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121750/fuzzy-rdd-issue/121806#121806) interesting.